# Facebook login activation denied by Facebook due to the closed store url

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, bluetooth-lowenergy, facebook-login

Now I'm developing an APP that uses Bluetooth functions on iOS/Android.
It's not published yet since it is under development.

As you may know, the simulator on iOS doesn't have the Bluetooth module.
However, Facebook requires us to submit the APP that can be launched on the simulator to authorize the Facebook login API.

I guess that is the reason why Facebook login API was working but now it's returning the error.

The beta test for the APP is planned, but I don't know how to get this API authorized by Facebook for the closed beta test.

I asked this on the Facebook forum, but got no reply there, so am asking here as well.
Any comments will be welcome (ex: I have to write down about xxx).

Best

Comment: You probably need to supply a version for testing that doesn't depend on Bluetooth.

Comment: I see.
I will try that as the fastest solution..!
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Facebook can review and revoke your public app permission and suddenly require an iOS store ID. This means you will need to use approved test user accounts to login, that have been authorised in the Facebook developer console, until your app is published on the AppStore.

You can add test users two ways in the [Facebook Developer console](https://developers.facebook.com/apps) (select your app first):

1. Roles -> Roles - Add your own Facebook account to the approved testers.
2. Roles -> Test Users - Create fake test accounts for the purpose.

[image]